# get the selected option from combo box

Tags: python, qt, combobox, pyqt4

Here is my python code converted from NetSim.ui to NetSim.py using pyuic4.

The combobox name is changed to Codecs.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'NetSim.ui'
#
# Created: Wed Oct 15 11:46:03 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
   _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
   def _fromUtf8(s):
      return s

try:
   _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
   def _translate(context, text, disambig):
      return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
   def _translate(context, text, disambig):
      return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_NetSim(object):
   def setupUi(self, NetSim):
      NetSim.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("NetSim"))
      NetSim.resize(641, 564)
      self.Codecs = QtGui.QComboBox(NetSim)
      self.Codecs.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 90, 81, 29))
      self.Codecs.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Codecs"))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
      self.Codecs.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))

   def retranslateUi(self, NetSim):

      NetSim.setWindowTitle(_translate("NetSim", "Dialog", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(0, _translate("NetSim", "Codecs", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(1, _translate("NetSim", "AMR-WB", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(2, _translate("NetSim", "AMR-WB+", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(3, _translate("NetSim", "VMR-WB", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(4, _translate("NetSim", "EVRC", None))
      self.Codecs.setItemText(5, _translate("NetSim", "EVRCb", No
```

I am using another python script to write my own functions and connect it to the widgets. I want to get the selected value of the combo box and use it (say print it) but it shows a red cross in the code on the line I want to get the selected value of Codec and I am unable to find the mistake.Error is : 
val = str(Ui_NetSim.Codecs.currentText())
AttributeError: type object 'Ui_NetSim' has no attribute 'Codecs'
Here it is:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from NetSim import Ui_NetSim
from PyQt4.Qt import QString
from __builtin__ import str

class AppGui(QtGui.QDialog,Ui_NetSim):

   def __init__(self):
      QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)

      self.ui = Ui_NetSim()
      self.ui.setupUi(self)

      self.ui.Codecs.activated.connect(self.select_Codec)

    def select_Codec(self):

     val = str(Ui_NetSim.Codecs.currentText())
     print val


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = AppGui()
ui = Ui_NetSim()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why can't you just use self.ui.Codecs.currentText()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access the class variable `Codecs` of the class `Ui_NetSim`. However, `Codecs` is an instance attribute of `Ui_NetSim` and thus only exists for instances of the class `Ui_NetSim`. This you should access it through `self.ui.Codecs.currentText()`

So your method becomes:

```
def select_Codec(self):
    val = str(self.ui.Codecs.currentText())
    print val
```

You also seem to have an extra `ui = Ui_NetSim()` towards the bottom of your program.

```
window = AppGui()
ui = Ui_NetSim() # Delete this line, it is doing nothing!
window.show()
```

Comment: Your answer was very well explained along with the reason what was my mistake. Thank you very much. @three_pineapples